# How to initialize a variable of date type in Java?

Tags: java, date, variables

```java
import java.util.Date;
Date firstDate;
```

I don't know how to initialize the `firstDate` for example for String you say

```
String line1="First line"
```

but what is the format for date can you give me an example?

Comment: That depends on what constructor you want to use. The most basic one is `Date firstDate = new Date();`. However, there are other constructors which you can use as well, where you can directly provide a `long` for the time or a `string` like '2015-12-06 17:01:00'

Comment: To future readers: `Date` is considered obsolete. You should use classes from the `java.time` package instead. [Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34120780/507738) to the abovementioned question for more info.

Answer (score 13):

Here's the Javadoc in Oracle's website for the Date class: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html
If you scroll down to "Constructor Summary," you'll see the different options for how a Date object can be instantiated. Like all objects in Java, you create a new one with the following:

```
Date firstDate = new Date(ConstructorArgsHere);
```

Now you have a bit of a choice. If you don't pass in any arguments, and just do this,

```
Date firstDate = new Date();
```

it will represent the exact date and time at which you called it. Here are some other constructors you may want to make use of:

```
Date firstDate1 = new Date(int year, int month, int date);
Date firstDate2 = new Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min);
Date firstDate3 = new Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min, int sec);
```

Comment: Careful, these last 3 initializations are deprecated

Answer (score 13):

**java.util.Date** constructor with parameters like
<strike>new Date(int year, int month, int date, int hrs, int min)</strike>.
is deprecated and preferably do not use it any more. Oracle documentation prefers the way over **java.util.Calendar**. So you can set any date and instantiate Date object through the getTime() method.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(2018, 11, 31, 59, 59, 59);
Date happyNewYearDate = calendar.getTime();
```

Notice that month number starts from 0

Answer (score 9):

To parse a Date from a String you can choose which format you would like it to have. For example:

```
public Date StringToDate(String s){

    Date result = null;
    try{
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        result  = dateFormat.parse(s);
    }

    catch(ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return result ;
}
```

If you would like to use this method now, you will have to use something like this

```
Date date = StringToDate("2015-12-06 17:03:00");
```

For more explanation you should check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: It's Save my day, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

Use `Instant`, replacement for `java.util.Date`.

```
Instant.now()  // Capture current moment as seen in UTC.
```

If you must have a `Date`, convert.

```
java.util.Date.from( Instant.now() )
```

## java.time

The java.util.Date & .Calendar classes have been supplanted by the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. The new classes are a *tremendous* improvement, inspired by the successful Joda-Time library.

The java.time classes tend to use static [factory methods](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) rather than [constructors](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(object-oriented_programming)) for instantiating objects.

To get the current moment in UTC time zone:

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

To get the current moment in a particular time zone:

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
```

If you must have a java.util.Date for use with other classes not yet updated for the java.time types, convert from `Instant`.

```
java.util.Date date = java.util.Date.from( zdt.toInstant() );
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

To initialize to current date, you could do something like:

```
Date firstDate = new Date();
```

To get it from String, you could use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) like:

```
String dateInString = "10-Jan-2016";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
try {
    Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    //handle exception if date is not in "dd-MMM-yyyy" format
}
```

Answer (score 2):

2020 update: use LocalDate for simple dates.

We would then initialize the date 23 Oct 1988 as follows:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(1988,10,23);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use java.util.Calendar to initialize date:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

//To Initialize Date to current Date
Date date = calendar.getTime();

//To Initialize Date to a specific Date of your choice (here I'm initializing the date to 2022-06-15)
calendar.set(2022, Calendar.JUNE, 15);
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

The format of the date can then be converted using SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: The `Calendar` class is poorly designed and long outdated. Also you may not get a `GregorianCalendar` object from `getInstance`, leading `set(2022, Calendar.JUNE, 15)`to give you a nonsensical result. And `SimpleDateFormat` is even worse.  Use [the answer by Basil Bourque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34120780/5772882) instead.