# get number of the week in the year where first day of the week is Sunday

Tags: java, date

I'm trying to get the number of the week for a date , In my country the week begins on Sunday so the week number of 6/5/2016 is 23 but it returning 22 because the ISO week in JAVA starts from Monday , I have used the following methods but it's not working

```
 mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
  int weekNum = mCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR); //returns 22 I need 23 
 // I have tried the following method but it has no effect 
 mCalendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
```

note that I can't use the Time Class I can only use Java 7

Comment: FYI, much of the java.time functionality built into Java 8 and later is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). Further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figured out how to change it 
you need to set up two things 
1-first day of the week 
2-the minimal day of week

```
setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);    
setMinimalDaysInFirstWeek(7);
```

this will tell the calendar to make the fist day is sunday and with 7 days minimal week

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 version full answer:

```java
public<T extends Temporal> long getWeekNumber(T tObj) {
    DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek  = DayOfWeek.SUNDAY; // set your
    Temporal firstDayOfThisYear = tObj.with(TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfYear());
    Temporal firstDayOfWeekInMonth = firstDayOfThisYear
             .with(TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(1, firstDayOfWeek));
    return ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(tObj, firstDayOfWeekInMonth);
}
```

The parameter can be any `Temporal` type, even the `Temporal` itself.

Comment: From the documentation of `Temporal`: *This interface is a framework-level interface that should not be widely used in application code. Instead, applications should create and pass around instances of concrete types, such as `LocalDate`.* This answer is still better than any of the others, though.

Comment: @OleV.V., agree, so I changed the answer to fit the situation in more save way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know from where you are but Java has an awesome Calendar which allows the following:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE);
int weekNumber = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
System.out.println("Number of week: " + weekNumber);
// produces 24

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.UK);
int weekNumber = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
System.out.println("Number of week: " + weekNumber);
// produces 22
```

You could use the locale constants to specify your location and i think you will get the right number of weeks.

Edit:
Now I see the failure in your code. Please note that Java works from the top to the button of your code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
// First set the first day of the week ...
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
// ... and than you could ask the calendar for the week
int weekNumber = calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
// will produce 23
System.out.println("Number of week: " + weekNumber);
```

Comment: I've tried this option but it's not working I need 23

Comment: Sorry I see my mistake a bit to late. I edited my post so that your ask should be answered.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you are from.
I'm french and that works perfectly this way :

```
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
mCalendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.SUNDAY);
int weekNum = mCalendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
System.out.println(weekNum); // --> 23
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the current moment.
   See this Question: [How to initialize a variable of type date in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34119441/642706)
2. Determine the first Sunday of the year.
   Handled thoroughly in this question: [How to get all the Sunday's of a year](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590385/642706)
3. Count weeks between that first Sunday and current moment.
   See the Question: [Get the number of weeks between two Dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9963147/642706)